# wordpress how to echo script in head from plugin options page via textarea?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I know how to echo in the head but when i paste a script in the textbox in my options page it comes out like this:

```
&lt;script&gt;
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i[&#039;GoogleAnalyticsObject&#039;]=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,&#039;script&#039;,&#039;//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js&#039;,&#039;ga&#039;);

  ga(&#039;create&#039;, &#039;UA-48019065-1&#039;, &#039;elegantdevelopment.eu&#039;);
  ga(&#039;send&#039;, &#039;pageview&#039;);

&lt;/script&gt;
```

instead of this:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-48019065-1', 'elegantdevelopment.eu');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I checked my database and the option is stored as the second example display when i check in phpmyadmin

Here is the code i have for to insert the snippet:

```
function PrintAnalytics( $post ){
    global $post;
    $analytics = esc_attr(get_option('basic_seo_analytics'));
    echo "\r\n" . $analytics . "\r\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly what esc_attr() is supposed to do. If you just want to do a sanity check on what's being output, consider using [wp_kses](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses) and telling it to only let `<script>` tags through.

Comment: Thanks,i removed the esc_attr() and t worked perfect.